# algorithm to generate shapes

Tags: algorithm, geometry, shapes

I need to be able to generate shapes based on multiple circles. So for example:
If I want to put 8 circles around a square, how to calculate the size of the square that is going to touch each surrounding circles.
Same issue for a circle or ellipse.

I try to add some image in ascii format, not sure it is clear.

```
                                        

                     @@@@@           @@@@@                    
                   @@@@@@@@@@     @@@@@@@@@@                  
                  @@@@@ @@@@@@   @@@@@@ @@@@@                 
                 @@@@      @@@@ @@@@      @@@@                
                @@@@        @@@@@@@        @@@@               
                @@@          @@@@@          @@@               
               @@@            @@@            @@@              
               @@@            @@@            @@@              
               @@             @@@             @@              
               @@@            @@@            @@@              
               @@@            @@@            @@@              
                @@           @@@@@           @@               
         @@@@@  @@@          @@@@@          @@@  @@@@@        
      @@@@@@@@@@@@@@        @@@ @@@        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@     
     @@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@     @@@@@ @@@@@     @@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@    
    @@@@       @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@      @@@@   
    @@@         @@@@@@@@@@@@       @@@@@@@@@@@@@        @@@@  
   @@@           @@@,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, @@@          @@@  
   @@@           @@@,                     ,@@@            @@  
   @@             @@,                     ,@@@            @@  
   @@             @@,                     ,@@             @@  
   @@             @@,                     ,@@@            @@  
   @@             @@,                     ,@@@            @@  
   @@@           @@@,                     , @@           @@@  
   @@@@         @@@@,                     , @@@          @@@  
    @@@@       @@@@ ,                     , @@@@        @@@   
     @@@@     @@@@  ,                     ,  @@@@     @@@@@   
      @@@@@@@@@@@   ,                     ,   @@@@@@@@@@@@    
       @@@@@@@@@    ,                     ,    @@@@@@@@@      
      @@@@@@@@@@@   ,                     ,   @@@@@@@@@@@@    
     @@@@     @@@@  ,                     ,  @@@@     @@@@@   
    @@@@       @@@@ ,                     , @@@@        @@@   
   @@@@         @@@@,                     , @@@          @@@  
   @@@           @@@,                     , @@           @@@  
   @@             @@,                     ,@@@            @@  
   @@             @@,                     ,@@@            @@  
   @@             @@,                     ,@@             @@  
   @@             @@,                     ,@@@            @@  
   @@@           @@@,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,@@@            @@  
   @@@           @@@@@@@@@@@       @@@@@@@@ @@@          @@@  
    @@@         @@@@@@@@@@@@@     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@        @@@@  
    @@@@       @@@@@@@    @@@@   @@@@    @@@@@@@@      @@@@   
     @@@@@@ @@@@@@@@       @@@@ @@@@       @@@@@@@@ @@@@@@    
      @@@@@@@@@@@@@         @@@@@@@         @@@@@@@@@@@@@     
         @@@@@  @@           @@@@@           @@  @@@@@        
               @@@            @@@            @@@              
               @@@            @@@            @@@              
               @@             @@@             @@              
               @@@            @@@            @@@              
               @@@            @@@            @@@              
                @@           @@@@@           @@               
                @@@         @@@@@@@         @@@               
                @@@@       @@@@ @@@@       @@@@               
                 @@@@@    @@@@   @@@@    @@@@@                
                  @@@@@@@@@@@     @@@@@@@@@@@                 
                    @@@@@@@@       @@@@@@@@
```

It should be the same for a circle instead of square in the middle.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everybody's answers i figured out how to generate python code for this problem.

## The following generate the requested shape

```
   import sys
   import pygame
   import math
   
   pygame.init()
   
   #create the screen
   window = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
  
   n=15; #n satellites
   r=20; #radius of a satellite
   R= abs( (2*r) / (2*(math.sin(math.pi/n))) ); # circumradius of the regular polygon.
   a=360/n; #rotating angle for vertex
   color = (255, 255, 255);
 
    
  #input handling (somewhat boilerplate code):
  while True:
      for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              sys.exit(0)
          if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
              mpos = pygame.mouse.get_pos();
              mx, my = event.pos
              for angle in range(0, 361):
                  theta = math.radians(angle)
                  x = R * math.cos(theta)
                  y = R * math.sin(theta)
                  print "Theta = "+str(theta)
                  if (angle % int(a) == 0):
                      pygame.draw.circle(window, color, (int(mx+x),int(my+y)), r,1);
              pygame.draw.circle(window, color, (mx,my), int(R-r),1);
              pygame.display.flip();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the square is 1x1 and r is the radius of the circles, then you can show that the following equation must hold:

```
2r + 1 = 2r/sqrt(2) + 2r + 2r/sqrt(2)            (*)
```

A little algebra shows r = sqrt(2) / 4 ~ 0.354.

From this it's pretty simple to get the centers of the circles.  I'll let you figure that out.

Here's a diagram made with this size for the circles that also shows how (*) is obtained:

[image: Diagram showing how (*) is obtained]

If you have ellipses all of the same size, just scale the problem by their aspect ratio on one side.

Comment: Gene, thanks for your reply. Actually, this is not exactly what I wanted. Probably my explanation was incorrect. I know the diameter and radius of the circle. I need to know how to place a square in the middle of those circles. Your equation still works?

Comment: How is this derived? Do you assume a symmetrical solution? For symmetry the centre of the circle must be equidistant to a line bisecting the square vertically and a line bisecting it diagonally and the top of the square. But I don't think this can be done because if you bisect the 90 degree angle between two of the lines mentioned and the 135 degree angle between another two what you get is not an isosceles triangle as you would expect from a circle of constant radius.

Comment: I added a picture.  Sure the derivation works.  It shows the ratio of the radius to the square's side is .354: r / s = .354.  So if you know r, then the size of the square is r/.354.  If you have elipses, just scale the problem on one axis to make them circles. Solve for the square, then do the inverse scale to get a rectangle.

Comment: Gene, thanks for the picture, it makes sense. mcdowella, yes it must be symmetrical, so always the same number of circles on each side of the square. So, Gene solution seems to work in any cases. Same if it is not a square but rectangle.